# WinJS Promise causes JavaScript exception in base.js

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps, winjs

I am trying to implement a service inside of my WinJS Windows 8 App, the service needs to call winjs httpClient. I want my service to return a promise while it waits for the promise returned by httpClient . My service code is as follows

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var _httpClient = new Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient();
    var _infoUri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("https://news.google.com/");

    var _getLatestInfo = function () {
        return WinJS.Promise(function (completeCallback, errorCallback, progressCallback) {
            // invoke the httpclient here
            _httpClient.getAsync(_infoUri)
            .then(function complete(result) {
                completeCallback(result);
            }, function error(result) {
                errorCallback(result);
            }, function progress(result) {
                progressCallback(result);
            });
        });
     };

    WinJS.Namespace.define("DataService", {
        getLatestInfo: _getLatestInfo
    });
})();
```

And I call my service method as follows

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    WinJS.UI.Pages.define("/pages/home/home.html", {
        // This function is called whenever a user navigates to this page. It
        // populates the page elements with the app's data.
        ready: function (element, options) {
            // TODO: Initialize the page here.
            DataService.getLatestInfo().then(function () { }, function () { }, function () { });
        }
    });
})();
```

This does not work and I get an error like this

```
Exception was thrown at line 2018, column 13 in ms-appx://microsoft.winjs.2.0/js/base.js
0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method '_setState''
```

I tried simplifying my service as follows with no luck.

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    var _getLatestInfo = function () {
        return WinJS.Promise(function (a, b, c) { });
    };

    WinJS.Namespace.define("DataService", {
        getLatestInfo: _getLatestInfo
    });
})();
```

I don't know what the error is trying to tell me and how to correct this.

Comment: I just figured it out, I was missing the 'new' just before WinJS.Promise. Since WinJS.Promise is a class it apparently need to be newed. The error message only confused me more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figured it out, I was missing the 'new' just before WinJS.Promise. Since WinJS.Promise is a class it apparently need to be newed. The error message only confused me more.

Comment: Glad you found your answer--yes, WinJS.Promise is an instantiable class, not a method. I'm curious, at the same time, why you need a new WinJS.Promise if you're not doing anything other than calling the competed/error/progress callbacks as shown in your code. You're already getting a promise from _httpClient.getAsync, so you could just return that promise directly. If you wanted to do more processing, then you can attach your own handlers using .then() and return the promise that comes back from .then. That promise will be fulfilled when your handlers are finished.

Comment: @KraigBrockschmidt-MSFT do you mean I could do 
    `var _getLatestInfo = function () { 
        return    _httpClient.getAsync(_infoUri);
    }`

I come from Angular, where you use pr = q.prmise() and then invoke an async method, call pr.resolve() in the completion routine of the async method and pr.reject() in the error handler, I was just following the same pattern.

Comment: Correct. An async method in WinRT returns a promise directly, and you can pass that promise around to any interested party. And according to the Promises/A convention (which WinJS uses), the .then() method returns another promise that's fulfilled them handlers given to the original promise are complete. This would be helpful if your _getLatestInfo wanted to do something more with the data from getAsync prior to fulfilling the promise that you return from _getLatestInfo. What you're doing isn't wrong, just redundant. :)